# How to parse YouTube Playlist into ListView

Tags: android, listview, youtube, gdata, playlist

I have a GDATA link that contains a playlist from a public YouTube Channel. I need the videos of this playlist to appear in a listview. Is this possible? If os, how can I implement it? Could someone point me towards an example?

EDIT:

Here is the gdata link I need to parse:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/interactivemedialab1/playlists/42E77F93E83D3FE4

Comment: Can you show us an example of the GDATA link?

Comment: I was looking to[YouTube's API](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists.html#Retrieving_playlists) and I see something interesting... If you use this link: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/42E77F93E83D3FE4 you have the playlist info, them, parsin XML you can fill the ListView

Comment: Refer this [blog](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/) Happy coding..........!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a list try searching the API Demos, loads of list view example there with code you can use. And as LeiNaD rightly pointed out first parse the XML using XMLPullParser or XMLSAXParser.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my sample Android application for displaying a YouTube playlist in a list view.

https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist

Note that you MUST have a valid API key for this sample application to work. You can register your application with the Google Developer Console and enable the YouTube Data API. You need to Register a Web Application NOT an Android application, because the API key that this sample app uses is the "Browser Key".